# javascript for loop variable and recursion

Tags: javascript

I have an issue where I have recursion inside of a for loop:

```
function func(node) {
    for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
       func(node.children[i]);
    } 
}
```

Obviously because JavaScript does not have block scope, the same i variable is getting modified each time the function is called.  What is the best way to remedy this?  Assume regular EcmaScript 3 and I can't use JavaScript 1.7 "let".

I know this has been asked before, but the other questions don't seem to show recursion, they show one function call where a closure could be used.

Comment: Can you post some example data for `node`? JavaScript scopes variables to the containing `function` or object literal, so each recursive call to `func` should get its own `i`.

Comment: Agree. tested in some other case. Can you post some example in jsfiddle.com ?

Comment: This function looks like it just loops (recursively) for a bit (assuming that the node has children)...is there something that it's supposed to do?

Comment: If you don't want text nodes, then your code should work fine (in browsers that support `children`). Just throw a little code in there that does something to `node`, and you're set. Paste this code into the console, and you'll get a nice orange border on everything: `function func(node) {for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {if(node.nodeType === 1) node.style.border="1px solid orange";func(node.children[i]);}} func(document.body);`

Comment: ok, this was an unrelated problem where the length of children was being modified.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cache the length of the array so you would have the following:

```
function recurse(node) {
    for(var i = 0, count = node.children.length; i < count; i++) {
        recurse(node.children[i]);
    }
}
```

You should always cache especially when you're dealing with HTMLCollections.

Answer (score 10):

Just use Crockford's `walkTheDOM` function:

```
function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

You pass in the root node and the function that you want to run for each node, like so:

```
var root = document.getElementById('wrap');

walkTheDOM(root, function(node) {
    console.log( node.nodeName );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/VKWTt/

Comment: This works for DOM elements only but the question is asked in a general manner.

Comment: @FLekschas It works for all types of nodes: https://jsbin.com/daruzo/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Okay my wording was wrong. Nodes could anything, not just a DOM node, for example a plain object: https://jsbin.com/yepoqixowe/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 7):

Was this facing issue, like during recursion of a function the variable values got replaced. the recursion was inside **for** loop, so the variables inside the **for** loop where modified.

Use **var** to declare variables that are modified at recursion.

Comment: refer link **[var and not using var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)**, will give more insight on this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you example should work.  The variable `i` is declared local, so when you recurse a new 'i' is used.

Javascript does global and local variables!

Answer (score 2):

You've already defined 'i' as a variable in a broader scope ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused. `i` is declared locally and so it's *not* the same `i` variable getting modified. Tested on this very page:

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
function func(node) {
    for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
       console.log([i, node]);
       func(node.children[i]);
    } 
}
func(span);

// returns
// [0, <span id="hlinks-user">...</span>]
// [1, <span id="hlinks-user">...</span>]
// [2, <span id="hlinks-user">...</span>]
// [0, <a href="/users...">...</a>]
// [3, <span id="hlinks-user">...</span>]
// [0, <span title="1 silver...">...</span>]
// [1, <span title="1 silver...">...</span>]
// [4, <span id="hlinks-user">...</span>]
// [0, <span title="7 bronze...">...</span>]
// [1, <span title="7 bronze...">...</span>]
// [5, <span id="hlinks-user">...</span>]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 function DragDropChanges(nodeChanged) {
        if (nodeChanged.children != null) {
            for (i = 0; i < nodeChanged.children.length;
                var temp = i;
                DragDropChanges(nodeChanged.children[i]);
                i = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```