# Please help me with a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

Good day. There is a recursive function:

```js
function f(counter) {
    counter--;
    document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter);
    
    if(counter != 0) {
        f(counter);
    }
    
    document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter);
}

f(3);
```

I do not understand how it works.

In the function gets 3 - value counter. Then the counter is decreased, it becomes 2. The next step is displayed with the value of the blue section 2. Then the condition that the counter is not 0 - function recursively calls itself. On the next start counter value decreases and becomes 1. Then the unit is displayed in the blue section. Then again triggered the condition, because even counter is not 0, the function calls itself again, reducing the counter to 0 and outputs 0 in the blue section. The next step counter falls into a condition in which the recursive calls terminate. Function outputs 0 in the yellow section. But then I wonder why the terminal 1 and 2 in the yellow section?

I understand why the output of 2, 1, 0 in the blue section - because the condition is triggered if (counter! = 0) and the function calls itself. If counter == 0 condition is not triggered and f (0) terminates the call - Conclusions 0 in yellow section. But why then completing the previous function calls - 1 and 2 outputs them in the yellow section, and not in the blue, it's not me that's understandable.

Comment: why all the not-love ?

Comment: Advanced users sometimes forget that recursion can be difficult for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `counter` is a local variable scoped to function `f`.

```
// value of counter = 2
document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter);

if(counter != 0) {
    f(counter) // calling f(2), must wait for function to return before continuing.
}

// after return, the value of counter is still 2 because it's a local variable
document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter);
```

Answer (score 4):

Recursion can be confusing if you haven't dealt with it, but I will try to explain:

You call:`f(3)`

So it enters and calls: `document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter);`

which prints then blue line with a 2 as the counter is 2 after the `counter--`, then it calls `f(2)` (because `counter != 0` as it is 2.)

So it calls: `document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter);`

which prints then blue line with a 1 as the counter is 1 after the `counter--`, then it calls `f(1)` (because `counter != 0` as it is 1.)

So it calls: `document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter);`

which prints then blue line with a 0 as the counter is 0 after the `counter--`, then it does not call `f(0)` (because `counter == 0`)

so now we complete the function we are in (where 'counter == 0') and it calls: `document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter);`

which prints then yellow line with a 0 as the counter is 0

then we go back to the function were we called `f(0)` from and `counter == 1` and that calls `document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter);`

which prints then yellow line with a 1 as the counter is 1

then we go back to the function were we called `f(1)` from and `counter == 2` and that calls `document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter);`

which prints then yellow line with a 2 as the counter is 2

I know this is confusing but I hope it helps?

*** *EDIT* *** Here is my more detailed and hopefully very clear explanation!

Here is my try:

```
function f(3) {
    counter--;
    document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter);

    if(counter != 0) {
        f(counter) // counter equals 2
    }

    document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter);
}
```

So lets just replace `f(counter)` aka `f(2)` above with what is actually being called (placing counter w/ counter2 because they are separate variables:

```
function f(3) {
    counter--;
    document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter);

    if(counter != 0) {
            counter2 = counter;
            counter2--;
            document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter2);

            if(counter2 != 0) {
                f(counter2) // counter2 equals 1
            }

            document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter2);
        }
    }

    document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter);
}
```

Now again, lets just replace `f(counter2)` aka `f(1)` above with what is actually called (replacing counter2 w/ counter3 as again they are separate variables.)

```
function f(3) {
    counter--;
    document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter); // prints 2

    if(counter != 0) {
            counter2 = counter;
            counter2--;
            document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter2); // prints 1

            if(counter2 != 0) {
                 counter3 = counter2;
                 counter3--;
                 document.write("<p style='background: blue'>" + counter3);  // prints 0

                 if(counter3 != 0) { // counter3 equals 0 so this is false
                     f(counter3);  // this is never called because counter3 DOES equal 0
                 }

                 document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter3);  // prints 0
            }

            document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter2); // prints 1
        }
    }

    document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter); // prints 2
}
```

Comment: I was about to write something similar. It might also help if you use the browser debug tools to set a break point at the top of your script and trace through the execution. 1) It will help your learn how to use the step over and step into functions 2) It will show as detailed above, exactly what is happening

Comment: @E.Maggini I updated and added much more detail.  I think it will be more useful than a stack trace.  IMO

Comment: @SimplyCraig, thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I will try to understand. I do not know much English, but be sure to turn. Thank you again.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov You are very welcome, feel free to comment any questions and I will try to better explain.  Happy Coding! :)

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov also accept the answer when you have a chance so people know this was resolved

Comment: I agree that in this case your information is infinitely more helpful. But as a sub-topic, learning how to the use the debug tools can be VERY useful when trying to figure out "why" or "how" something works. http://devtoolsecrets.com/

Comment: @SimplyCraig, I almost realized remains to understand why since this code when the function completes f(1) and f(2), it prints the value in the yellow counter? Why it displays 0 in yellow, I realized, because the condition is not working and she ends the call f(0) displays it in yellow. And that is why on the function completes f(1) and f(2) again to display in yellow?

Comment: Because in recursion when I call a function in the middle of a function after that function exits aka `f(0)` ends it then continues from `f(0)` inside of `f(1)` then it exits the if statement (inside `f(1)`) and calls `document.write("<p style='background: yellow'>" + counter);`

Comment: @SimplyCraig, now all became clear. Your explanation helped me a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> But why then completing the previous function calls - 1 and 2 outputs them in the yellow section, and not in the blue, it's not me that's understandable.

Because after executing f(3), function is not terminated and is awaiting for completion of f(2) call. When it is done, then it goes further and writes 3 into yellow div. And so on for each counter.

Imagine `f` calls not itself inside but some other function `myFunc`. It waits until `myFunc` is ended. With recursion the same flow.

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because the variable "counter" is a local variable into function f. 
You should cache the variable in order for the f to run as you describe. 
Check this answer here: [javascript for loop variable and recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419128/javascript-for-loop-variable-and-recursion) it describes a similar problem and its solution.

Answer (score 0):

I realized we recursively calls f (2), f (1), f (0), but we do not end the call when if (counter! = 0), this condition will not work. The display will 0 in yellow. Now we need to complete the rest of the function f (1) and f (2), these functions have `document.write ("<p style = 'background: yellow'>" + counter) ;`. It turns out that when we complete these challenges is output 1 and 2 in the yellow.